# Generating a random string in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I need to generate a random, two-word identifier field for each Mongo doc I'm inserting via Node.

I found random-words, an NPM module. It's great, except that I can only generate the random string server-side. When I try to use it in the client code, the function randomWords() comes back as undefined.

Here's my relevant server code (I took out the error handlers for the sake of brevity):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// random words
var randomWords = require('random-words');
// Database
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/test');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Make the db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

module.exports = app;
```

And here's my server stuff (my global js file, not the route - though it doesn't work in either):

```
// DOM Ready =============================================================
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ident = randomWords(2);

    // Add User button click
    $('#button').on('click', addUser); //addUser is a function in this doc

});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm exporting the module and I'm able to access other stuff from the server-side code (like the database), I just don't know where I'm messing it up.

Comment: how are you including the random-words module in your client side code?

Comment: How do you mean? (This is probably my problem, sorry, I'm kind of new to Node.)

Comment: do you need it to be a real word or can it be just a random string?

Comment: Real word unfortunately, or this would be way easier.

Comment: Are you using browserify or some other modular script loader? If not, how are you exposing the 'require' function in your client side code? Normally, `var randomWords = require('random-words');` will not work in the browser on its own.

Comment: Ah, this is where I've been going wrong then! I assumed that since my database is available that other modules are available too. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: I just used Browserify, which kept breaking trying to include Monk (see below), managed to sidestep that with the --ignore-missing flag, included the bundle.js file in my jade layout so things should now be working ... but, the randomWords() function is still undefined. I don't know what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using vmkcom's suggestion above. I'm posting for others who might benefit from it because I had a really hard time diagnosing this problem and figuring out how to solve it. NOTE: This is a hacky fix that I suspect isn't recommended (but it works in this instance because, as vmkcom pointed out, the index.js file is pretty simple), so if you have a more elegant solution, please feel free to respond below.

Node modules, as helpfully pointed out above, are not automatically accessible to your browser. However you can make them so with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), which is, in theory,  great. But, when I ran Browserify, it didn't work and when I got it to run it only caused more errors.

What I did instead was take the index.js file from the random-words github (located [here](https://github.com/punkave/random-words)), renamed it random.js, and included it in my public /javascripts folder. I then linked to it in my layout.jade template file like this:

```
    body
    block content
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/global.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/random.js')
```

It isn't ideal, but it does work. As I said this is quick and dirty at its quickest and dirtiest, so if you have a better way, please share.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it in server side for env file you can do it like:

```js
export const randomString = (length: number) => {
  if (process.env.SECRET_KEY === undefined)
    process.env.SECRET_KEY = [...Array(length)]
      .map(() => (~~(Math.random() * 36)).toString(36))
      .join("");
  return process.env.SECRET_KEY;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just copy code of `random-words` module index.js into your client code and rewrite `module.exports = words` as `window._words = words`

Or use some module system at client code as `require.js`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean copy the source of the module's index.js file into my global.js file? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of including modules via npm?

Comment: you can't include npm module to browser. Broserify helps with that, but if you don't want to deal with it - just copy.

For browser libraries you need to use `bower` or something like that, but it seems that `random-words` exists only in npm.

npm - for node.js, not all libraries can be ported to browser

Comment: Okay .. I used browserify on my app.js (server) code and exported it as bundle.js. I included this in my jade layout. However, the function is still coming back as undefined.

Comment: how do you call that function? And how looks your bundle.js? How do you require bundle.js?

Comment: Just found the problem - I'm using Monk and Browserify fails because it can't include monk: Cannot find module './lib-cov/' from '/.../node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin'

Comment: Posting this for others who might be having this problem: You can use the --ignore-missing flag with browserify to skip missing files. Browserify spat out bundle.js, I included it, but it's still saying that the randomWords() function is undefined. Dunno what else to try here.

Comment: look at the bundle.js. It's pretty simple code to investigate the problem

I said about copy code just cause it's haven't any serious logic